# ngenius-payment not able inegrate, i followed by DOCS but giving me error. It should go to payment page of

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, laravel-6

```
public function payment(Request $request){
    //===============Getting Access Token from N-Genius Platform Network===============================================
    $apikey = "api-key";        // enter your API key here
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-gateway.sandbox.ngenius-payments.com/identity/auth/access-token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "accept: application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json",
        "authorization: Basic ".$apikey,
        "content-type: application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  "{\"realmName\":\"ni\"}");
    $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    $access_token = $output->access_token;
    //===============END Getting Access Token from N-Genius Platform Network=============================================
    //===============N-Genius Payment Gateway will redirect to the pay page =============================================
    $postData = new StdClass();
    $postData->action = 'Sale';
    $postData->amount = new StdClass();
    $postData->amount->currencyCode = 'AED';
    $postData->amount->value = 1 * 100;
    $postData->language = 'en';
    $postData->emailAddress = 'form user email';
    $postData->billingAddress['firstName'] = 'form first name';
    $postData->billingAddress['lastName'] = 'form last name;
    $postData->merchantAttributes['redirectUrl'] = 'redirection page route';
    $token = $access_token;
    $json = json_encode($postData);
    $outlet = "outlet-id";
    $token = $access_token;
    $json = json_encode($postData);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-gateway.sandbox.ngenius-payments.com/transactions/outlets/'.$outlet.'/orders');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
        'Content-Type: application/vnd.ni-payment.v2+json',
        'Accept: application/vnd.ni-payment.v2+json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    $order_reference = $output->reference;
    $order_paypage_url = $output->_links->payment->href;
    header("Location: ".$order_paypage_url);                              // execute redirect
    //die();
    curl_close ($ch);
    //===============END N-Genius Payment Gateway will redirect to the pay page =============================================
}
```

Anyone can help me Please. Please Guide me How to integrate ngenius-payment gateway to laravel app Their documentation not enough to integrate with laravel. i am planing to choose with making payments from their websites, and return back to us with a return URL.

Answer (score 0):

did you get the accessToken?
if yes then try with this post data

```
{
    "action": "SALE",
    "amount": {
        "currencyCode": "AED",
        "value": 1700
    },
    "merchantAttributes" : { 
            "redirectUrl" : "url",
            "skipConfirmationPage": true,
            "cancelText": "Go to Homepage"
    },
    "emailAddress": "test11@order.com",
    "merchantOrderReference": "test-12"
}
```